# git-bash window title issue

Tags: bash, msys

I started a git-bash window, and type following commands :

```
git-bash ~$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.23(1)-release
git-bash ~$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
git-bash ~$ cd tmp
git-bash ~/tmp$
# Change of directory is NOT refelected on git-bash window title

git-bash ~/tmp$ ssh user@linux
[user@linux ~]$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.20(1)-release
[user@linux ~]$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
[user@linux ~]$ cd tmp
[user@linux ~/tmp]$
# Change of directory   IS   refelected on git-bash window title
```

Why does git-bash NOT update its own window title whereas a remote bash DOES ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither Bash nor the terminal will update the title automatically – it has to be updated by outputting the necessary control sequences either as part of `PS1` (at the same time when the prompt is shown) or through `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Some distributions already have a custom shell prompt that updates the terminal title, but some don't.

The control sequence that sets terminal title is usually `\e]0;NEW TEXT\e\\`. (There may be variations.) For example, to set the terminal title to `user@host /path` (i.e. `\u@\h \w`) you could use:

```
PS1+='\[\e]0;\u@\h \w\e\\\]'
```

That's `\[` to tell Bash an "invisible" (0-width) sequence starts;
`\e]0;` as the start of "set title" terminal command;
`\u@\h \w` as the Bash PS1 expansions for user@host and working directory;
`\e\\` as the terminator (`\a` is also acceptable though nonstandard);
and `\]` to end the "invisible" region.

This should be set in your `~/.bashrc`, near the other prompt customizations.